Does the negative multinomial distribution have a defined CDF?
I have a process that receives categorically distributed random inputs of 5 different types. The 5th type is considered "bad". If the process receives 4 bad inputs before receiving at least 3 of each good type of input, the process fails. I want to calculate the probability that the process will succeed.
I think I could compute this using the negative multinomial distribution. My idea was to take 1 - the integral of all the parts of the distribution that represent failures. However, it seems there isn't a defined CDF for the negative multinomial.
Does anyone know why this is the case? And if so, is the best one can do is just to sum up the PMFs of the failure cases and subtract them from 1?

Every random variable has a CDF.  What do you mean by "defined"?

Where does your link say it doesn't have a "defined CDF?"   Just because a formula isn't on Wikipedia doesn't mean it doesn't exist!

@whuber: I may be misunderstanding something. Don't CDFs require at least ordinal outcomes? How would one even define a CDF for a categorical RV? In the present case, one could probably define a "CDF-analogue" using a lexicographic ordering on the multiple outcome dimensions, $F(x):=P(X_1\leq x_1 \wedge\dots\wedge X_k\leq x_k)$ - but this at least requires a little thinking and definitional work compared to a one-dimensional ordinal RV. What am I missing?

@Stephan The details depend on what you mean by a "categorical RV," but all RVs have CDFs. Usually categorical outcomes are encoded as vector-valued random variables ("dummy coding" methods). Recall that by definition a random variable $X$ is a measurable function with values in a finite-dimensional real vector space, usually identified with $\mathbb R^p$ for some $p\ge 1.$  Also by definition its CDF is the function $$F_X:\mathbb R^p\to[0,1];\quad F_X(\mathbf x)=\Pr(X_1\le x_1,\ X_2\le x_2,\ \ldots,\ X_p\le x_p).$$

Sorry, to clarify - I know there must be a CDF of some sort, and I know that just because it isn't on Wikipedia doesn't mean it doesn't exist. As I mentioned, there is of course the definition of CDF for the negative multinomial where you just sum up the PMFs for all inputs where at least one value in the input vector is less than the given argument. What I'm asking is if there is a simpler form of the CDF than that, similar to how the negative binomial has a CDF defined using the regularized incomplete beta function. I am curious if an analogue exists for the negative multinomial.

@whuber, the CDF definition you provided is exactly what I'm hoping to compute here. I know I could do so by just summing up all the PMFs, but I didn't know if there was a more straightforward definition of the CDF for the negative multinomial than that (which is what I meant by "defined" - sorry for the imprecision in language).

It sounds like you are using "defined" in the sense of "a closed formula."  That's often a matter of what functions you are familiar with: for instance, one person's closed formula in terms of hypergeometric functions is another's sum.  That Wikipedia does not list any formula is usually a good hint that no convenient form of the CDF is known.
